# python type() without ouput in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Python: 3.10.4
Pycharm: 2022.1 CE

I have this simple code with Python shell command:

```
a = 1
type(a)
<class 'int'> <-- the result
```

But when I execute this code with Pycharm, I receive this output:

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Why I don't have the output of "type()"?

Comment: Because you never printed it. If you're not in the REPL, the last value is **not** printed by default.

Comment: Right.  The IDEs make people lazy.  Use `print(type(a))`.

Comment: Use print(type(a)), when you are using the python cli, you are using the interpreter. To run it as a program and get the type output, you'll have to use print. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just wrap type(a) with print function,

```
print(type(a))
```